# Count the words using ‘for’ PHP

Tags: php

#My Question
There are information like below

yes
yes
yes
yes
no
no
yes

and **I want to count how many **“no”** are in this list**.

and I wrote code using PHP.
but it doesn’t work and there are any error messages.
How can I solve this problem?

#My Code

```
<?php 

$sum = 0;
for ($i = 0 ; $i <= 7 ; $i++){

$input = fgets(STDIN);
 if($input == “no”){
 $sum++;
  }
}

echo $sum;

?>
```

Comment: How is your yes and no are displayed - are in an array OR string etc etc ?

Comment: You are missing the `;` off the line `$input = fgets(STDIN)`, also `fgets()` will have a newline on the end, so use `trim()` to remove this ( `if(trim($input) == "no"){` ). You should also set `$sum` to 0 before the loop.

Comment: The “quotes” here are different from the "normal" quotes that are valid in PHP

Comment: yes and no are string.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to initialise $sum variable with a value before for loop.

Place this line above your for loop:

```
$sum = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data is in an array then I hope the below code will help you

```
$data = array("yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes"); 
$sum = 0;

foreach($data as $arr){
    if($arr == "no"){
        $sum++;
    }
}
echo $sum;
```

If your data is in a different format, let know and I'll modify this code accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I confirmed using `gettype` then it was a string.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few assumptions to be made here, but I think the core thing which you are missing will be that the `fgets(STDIN)` would be returning a string, not an iteratable.

You can get the same functionality by doing:

```
<?php

$i = 0;
$sum = 0;
while(($data = fget('file')) !== false || $i <= 7){
   $i++;
   if($data == 'No'){
     $sum++;
   }
}
```