# How can I count the word using `for` syntax in PHP

Tags: php, sum, counting

There are information like:
`yes yes yes yes no no yes`

I want to count how many `no` are in this list.
I tried to get that result writing PHP code, but it doesn’t work and there are some error messages.

How can I solve this problem?

**My Code**

```
<?php 

$sum = 0;
for ($i = 0 ; $i <= 7 ; $i++){

$input = fgets(STDIN);
 if($input == “no”){
 $sum++;
  }
}

echo $sum;
?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count the words using ‘for’ PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62750185/count-the-words-using-for-php)

Comment: Yes,this is my question, but it has closed so I modified and repost it here.

Comment: What are the error messages?

Comment: There are no error message but it’s just show nothing in my console.

Comment: Which "list" do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `explode()` function.
And use space as separator.

```
<?php

$str = "yes no yes yes no";
$words_arr = explode(' ',$str);
$no_count=0;
$yes_count=0;
foreach ($words_arr as $value) {
  if($value=="no")
    $no_count++;

  if($value=="yes")
    $yes_count++;
}

echo $no_count;
echo "<br>";
echo $yes_count;
```

I have tested this code on http://phptester.net/

Answer (score 0):

A simple way you can do this is by using `substr_count()` which counts all occurrences of a string in another string.

```
<?php 
$input = fgets(STDIN);
$count_yes = substr_count($input, "yes");
$count_no = substr_count($input, "no");

echo "Yes: $count_yes";
echo "No: $count_no";
?>
```